# Does the web dyno with standard+ sleep on Heroku saving money?

Tags: java, heroku

I love the idea of the process-oriented model that Heroku is touting.

Before jumping into setting up a platform, I need to know if the standard1x/2x or higher will go to sleep.  It says that it "never sleeps", though is this for the entire billing period?

I can't find anything that says for sure that if it goes to sleep that you will not be charged.  It simply says $25 for 1 dyno.  I am just using a web dyno.

Does this mean if no one hits the app for 15 days, I'll only be charge $12 at the end of the month?

Answer (score 0):

A Standard-1x/2x dyno will not sleep after a period of inactivity. But you can manually scale it down by running:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=0
```

When it is scaled down, you will not be billed for it.

Comment: Is there an API to check to see if there are errors in the app?  Such as R12 and R14?

Comment: Here is the [Heroku API reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference). I don't think Error codes are an endpoint, but you could get that from a [logging add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries).